# How to fill a selectManyListbox from a database

Tags: jsf

I would like to know how I can fill a `h:selectManyListbox` from a database, i.e. not with static options.

Comment: Is not an answer from @BalusC satisfactory for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use `<f:selectItems>` in combination with a property which returns `List<SelectItem>`, or when you're already on JSF 2.0, a `List<SomeObject>`.

```
<h:selectManyListbox value="#{bean.selectedItems}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.selectItems}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

You can load the items from the DB in bean's constructor or `@PostConstruct` method.

```
public class Bean {

    private List<String> selectedItems;
    private List<SelectItem> selectItems;

    public Bean() {
        selectItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

        // Fill select items during Bean initialization/construction.
        // Below is just an example, you could replace this by getting a list
        // of some objects from DB and creating new items in a loop.
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem("value1", "label1"));
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem("value2", "label2"));
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem("value3", "label3"));
    }

    // Getters, etc
}
```